# XAML properties set order optimization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, filtering

I'm creating a control, named SystemTreeControl, that is a tree containing nodes.
There is 2 dependency properties:

- RootNode : binded to the root node of the tree
- Filter : binded to a delegate that defines if a node shall be displayed in the tree or not.

This is how I use it:

```
<controls:SystemTreeControl
    RootNode="{Binding RootNode}"
    Filter="{x:Static configuration:Configuration.DefaultFilter}"/>
```

When the RootNode property is set, the tree if generated. Then the filter is set, so the tree has to be cleared and generated again.
This is time consuming and not optimized.

Keep in mind that filter can also be null, so I cannot wait for the filter to be set to generate the tree.

The only solution I found is to change the property order in the XAML, so the filter is set prior to the root node:

```
<controls:SystemTreeControl
    Filter="{x:Static configuration:Configuration.DefaultFilter}"
    RootNode="{Binding RootNode}"/>
```

I don't like this solution as the optimization job is done outside the control, and the developer using this control has to be aware of it.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: You can initialize your filter with the default filter and let the user overwrite it if needed

Comment: Isn't it you code the that's working with those nodes? Can't you move that code somewhere else like it's loaded event so you'd have everything there.

Comment: @DenisSchaf : This is not solving my issue. If the user overwrites the filter by setting it in the XAML after settings the RootNode (like in my 1st code) then the tree has to be cleared and generated again. This is time consuming and not optimized.

Comment: @Andy What kind of loading event would you use to do this ?

Comment: Any frameworkelement has a loaded event and a control inherits that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=netframework-4.7.2